# Opening tomcat from the browser on different port than 8080

Tags: java, tomcat

I have nginx on 8080 port installed on my CentOS server, and I have installed java tomcat additionaly. It's also on 8080 by default, so I changed the port to some free one - 8085. The problem is that trying to get a response from it by opening `http://122.21.32.33:8085/` gives me `page not found` error.

Why is that so?

The service is started, I changed the connector tag in `server.xml` to:

```
 <Connector port="8085" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               useIPVHosts="true" />
```

Firing `netstat -ntpl | grep java` gives me:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN      8818/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8085                 :::*                    LISTEN      8818/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      8818/java
```

`ps -ef | grep tomcat` gives me:

```
tomcat    8818     1  0 17:56 ?        00:00:01 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djava.aw...
root      8862  8144  0 18:00 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto tomcat
```

Ports 8818 and 8862 don't work either. What's wrong?

Comment: Looks like it's listening on IPV6 and you're trying to connect on IPV4.

Answer (score 0):

Your netstat-Output says, that you are listening on IPv6. Then you try to connect form your browser via IPv4. You need to configure tomcat to make it listen on IPv4:

You basically have to add this:

```
JAVA_OPTS= "$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses"
```

to the end of your `catalina.sh` file.

Here is a [full guide](http://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/bind-apache-tomcat-ipv4-centos/) in case you need it.